# Removing Duplicate Lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm doing a program that inputs a series of numbers, and takes 6 of them to make different combinations of lottery numbers. When I create the different combinations, I want to remove duplicates, so that each combination is only printed once.
This is what I want to happen:

```
combo_list = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

And the output should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 4 5 6 7
1 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

The code I'm using is:

```
   final = []
    for sublist in combo_list:
        if sublist not in final:
            final.append(sublist)
    for item in final:
        item = (sorted(item, key=int))
        print (' '.join(str(n) for n in item))
```

However, I get an output with many duplicates when I use the code:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
.
.
.
```

Any ideas on what I have to change for each of the combinations to only print once?

Comment: Your algorithm appears to be flawed - you aren't approaching the problem right.  The number of combinations is known and python as the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library for dealing with this problem in a more efficient manner.

Comment: Think about whether you can modify your code to not generate the duplicates in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for this:

```
import itertools as it
ans = it.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 6)
```

The result is as it should be:

```
list(ans)

=> [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7),
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7),
    (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
    (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)]
```

If you need to print the numbers afterwards it's easy:

```
for r in ans:
    print ' '.join(str(s) for s in r) 

=> 1 2 3 4 5 6
   1 2 3 4 5 7
   1 2 3 4 6 7
   1 2 3 5 6 7
   1 2 4 5 6 7
   1 3 4 5 6 7
   2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: This is very useful, but I should have clarified; I was required to use recursion to solve this problem (which I did), so the final step was to eliminate the duplicates. Is there any alternative to itertools functions?

Comment: @user1778344 in the code you posted you didn't use recursion. Anyway, if you want to remove duplicates from a list of lists, transform it into a set of tuples: `set(tuple(x) for x in final)`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez You may also make the numbers strings to begin with so you don't need to convert them later

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, go ahead and try using the [combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module. In your case, you'll get:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],6)
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7)
(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)]
```

which is what I think you want.

Remember that the output of the `combinations` function is a generator.

Comment: Also, if you're interested, the documentation for the combination function in itertools gives a pure Python implementation of this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the source to [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) then:

```
def lotto(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

print list(lotto([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 6))
```

Comment: OP stated that the solution has to be recursive (even though his solution isn't recursive)

Comment: Sorry, I abbreviated my code, as it was quite long. I just posted the final few steps in the main function. By that point, the combinations had already been created, recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desire to simply remove the duplicates..  Use python [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

```
   final = []
    for sublist in combo_list:
        if sublist not in final:
            final.append(sublist)
    for item in set(tuple(x) for x in final):
        item = (sorted(item, key=int))
        print (' '.join(str(n) for n in item))
```

But FWIW - why re-create the wheel use the @Óscar López answer ;)

HTH

Comment: Lists are not hashable. See the last comment in my answer: what OP would need to do in the last loop is `for item in set(tuple(x) for x in final)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 comb_list= range(1, 8)
 rip_idx = 6
 for idx in range(len(comb_list)):
    final = comb_list[0:rip_idx -idx ] + comb_list[rip_idx- idx + 1: ]
    print final
```

A simple way to achieve it solve without any library